# ASP.NET memcache and sync many instances of the same application

Tags: asp.net, synchronization, memcached

In a single application (one instance) when I want to put something into the cache I used to do:

```
lock(sync) 
{
   // if cache is null
   // make sql and put data into cache
   // else
   // return data from cache
}
```

to prevent hitting the database from other request.

That was fine, baut what bout when I have a many instances of the same app? I cant use lock because it works only on the one instance. Of course I could use mutex but I've read that it is much slower than lock therefore I think that this is not a good way to solve this problem.

Do you guys have any idea? suggestions?

Best